# Magento 2.3.5 - Customer login frontend does not work

Tags: magento2.3, login

For some reason our customer login form on the frontend does not work anymore.
We still can login into the backend without any problems.

I check the log files, but there are not error's displayed. Also there is no frontend error displayed.

Anyone a idea how to solve this problem?

EDIT: First it seems to be a CAPTCHA problem, I get the following error;

```
You cannot proceed with such operation, your reCaptcha reputation is too low.
```

After that we disabled the CAPTCHA on frontend and then we get the following error;

```
The account sign-in was incorrect or your account is disabled temporarily. Please wait and try again later.
```

Account and login details are correct, but it does not load. Also the customer account is not disabled or blocked.

Anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of different reasons. The most common ones are because of a missconfiguration of sessions or cookies, f.e. like described here: [Magento2 customer login and registration session not working in frontend in chome?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/236643/magento2-customer-login-and-registration-session-not-working-in-frontend-in-chom)

or if you have this problem in your local dev environment and running the magento shop on a localhost domain and using chrome as browser, it could be also occur because of: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/customer-can-not-login-on-chrome-browser-in-magento-2-1-8/td-p/75467#

If both is not the case, it's maybe some more specific problem in your project. So maybe try to provide some more information if this does not help you further.

Comment: Thanks! It seems that it is a CAPTCHA problem, see my edit.